# Swift operators and nil

Tags: swift

What is the explanation for this behavior?

```
let x: Int? = nil
if x < 10 {
    print("x < 10")
}
```

It prints "x < 10". Shouldn't this produce a runtime error or at least a compiler warning?

EDIT:

*I submitted a bug report to Apple and they acknowledged it as an already existing duplicate of another report. So this will be handled/fixed by Apple in some way.*

Comment: It's interesting additionally because `Optional`s should be allowed to be declared with `let` - it looks like I thought wrong

Comment: It looks like a bug to me, it works even if you compare with nil directly like `if nil < -100`

Comment: It's hard to believe in a bug on such a basic level of the language.

Comment: [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I _hate it when_ Martin R beats me to the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two things happen here (whether we like it or not): *First,* there is an
operator

```
public func <<T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

which compares two optionals if the underlying type is comparable.
The behavior is not documented (as far as I know), but it seems that
`nil` aka `Optional<T>.None` is considered less than all non-nil
values `Optional<T>.Some(value)`.

*Second,* `enum Optional` has a constructor

```
/// Construct a non-`nil` instance that stores `some`.
public init(_ some: Wrapped)
```

Now in

```
if x < 10 { ... }
```

the lhs has the type `Optional<Int>`. The only candidate for the `<`
operator is the above-mentioned one comparing two optionals.
Therefore the rhs is inferred as an optional as well, so this
is equivalent to

```
if x < Optional<Int>.Some(10) { ... }
```

---

**Update:**

This feature has been removed in Swift 3 ([SE-0121 – Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)) and that code no longer compiles with Xcode 8
(currently beta 6).

Comment: great explanation. this is so gross though. :D

Comment: I just came to the same results. There is *some* documentation for `Comparable` protocol which is the one defining the default `<`, however, th e explanation completely ignores optionals.

Comment: It's particularly ugly as it seems co-erce the type. e.g. in a playground `x < Int(10)` returns true, but `nil < Int(10)` borks.

Comment: Thanks. If this is not a bug it should be considered as a bug on language design level. (or standard library level) I think everybody expects a compiler error or at least a warning.

Comment: Also strange:  let x: Int? = nil;  let y: Int = 10;  if x < y { print("x < y") };  Prints also "x < y". So I have explicitly declared y as non-optional.

Comment: @Darko: That't the same behaviour as in the code in your question. If the lhs is an optional then the rhs is wrapped into an optional as well.

Comment: I understand that the compiler could infer a literal as optional but not when I explicitly declare it as non optional. Seems "wrong" to me. (both cases) The Swift "way" is usually about non-implicit casting, but here it does.

Comment: @Darko: That is a good argument, and I don't have an answer to that.

Comment: @Darko Coercing to an optional is not really casting, it happens everywhere. We are using that all the time for `==` so why should `<` be different? The real problem is that comparison with `nil` is not documented.

Comment: To me it's not just about documenting it. Simple question: is nil smaller then 10? This comparison should not be possible. It created already a severe bug in my application code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `enum Optional`?

Comment: @Qbyte: Yes, indeed!

Comment: @Darko: I have posted a question at the Apple Developer Forum about *why* an implicit conversion is done here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23368.

Comment: @MartinR: I submitted a bug report to Apple and they acknowledged it as an already existing duplicate of another report. So this will be handled/fixed by Apple in some way.