# Able to perform equality test without unwrapping optional

Tags: swift, xcode7

In Swift, I am able to perform equality on an optional without unwrapping it.  Why? Does the equality operator automatically unwrap the content and perform the test?

e.g.

```
var s: String?
print(s == "hi")  // print "false\n"

s = "hi"
print(s == "hi") // print "true\n"
```

The above works without having to unwrap s.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216358/swift-operators-and-nil (and it's duplicate). – I also asked in the Apple Developer Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23368. The answer was *"Optionals are handled specially in Swift."*