# Normal typed variable cannot compare with nil but a literal can, why is that?

Tags: swift, null, compare

```
var a = 7
a != nil //Error: value of type 'Int' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed
7 != nil //--> false
0 > nil //true
-9999999 > nil //true
```

**Question** Very much like the code above, OK I got it from the compiler that it cannot compare `a` with `nil`, but why a literal `7` can compare with nil. I mean `7` is the created existing number, it can also never be `nil`, isn't it?

BTW
When I try the `-9999999 > nil` that also returns `true`, I finally get started to know the `nil` in the right way. 10 min ago I still think `-1 < nil` would return `true`. Would be nice if you can tell me a bit more about `nil`. What is it? It is not a pointer (different with Object-C). Is it just simply noting?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216358/swift-operators-and-nil and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172911/swift-nil-has-a-numeric-value.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the provided source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is from the Standard Library

```
/// A type that can represent either a `Wrapped` value or `nil`, the absence
/// of a value.
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : _Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
   case None
   case Some(Wrapped)
```

The point to look out for is that Optional can be nil literal convertible.

Second this is how the comparision is defined in the Swift library which can be seen on github on this link:[Github Swift Optional Implementation Code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift)

```
public func < <T : Comparable> (lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}

public func > <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l > r
  default:
    return rhs < lhs
  }
}
```

Which when combined can be used to reason your code.

The strategy is as follows:

```
 0 > nil
```

1. 0 is implicity deduced to Optional or Int?.
2. Swift Optinal has **<** which says if the **lhs is nil** then `return true`
3. Swift Optional has **>** which says if the **rhs is nil** then `return true`

To simplify step 2 and 3: **nil is always smaller than .some**

The comparision of the >/< doesnot take into account the element type when either side is nil.

And in the case of

```
  var a = 7
  a != nil
```

Its obvious that Int cannot be compared with Optional.None and this is exactly what that compiler shouts out.

Hope this explains it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed explanation and help. It helps a lot